# Is my water heater installed properly?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, hot-water

Why do all 3 pipes..the hot, the cold, and the over flow valve run hot water. I can tell by the touch. the overflow which I'm used to having a free flowing tube attached to a pan is connected to a pipe going through the next apartments water heater. and when he. uses water mine drains/fills up. I guess he did this to save himself money but its costing me a fortune
Also there is a knob in the lower part of the wall with just a handle...maybe should be the cold pipe wall entrance? Or is this sounding normal more like just a slipped / broken pipe that is supposed to bring the cold water down to lower chamber?

Comment: Please provide pictures of the installation

Comment: If the PVR valve has been removed/disabled, you do not have a proper hot water tank install. This is dangerous and should be inspected/corrected.

Comment: The "overflow" pressure relief pipe should not normally have any water flowing. Are you sure it goes to your neighbors apartment or does it drain outside somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

All three pipes are hot near the water heater because they are warmed by the heat from the water heater, through conduction and convection. This does not indicate an incorrect water heater install.

Comment: Note that this means insulating a foot or two of the inlet pipe may be helpful,  along with insulating the hot-water pipes. Unless you're counting on that to heat your basement, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Partially open a hot water spigot somewhere, then feel the pipes.  The cold inlet should definitely feel cold after some water has run.

While no water is running, heat is being transmitted in all directions.